# magento tier price issue in 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, price, tierprice

I am using **Magento 1.9.3**

Tier price is applied on checkout page when customer is not log in but it's not applied when customer is login,

Can not find any solution to fix this.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Login to admin and check product price section:

[image]

If you want to apply tier price for all customer then select "ALL GROUPS"

I hope it will resolve your issue.